# using switch in strings

Tags: java, switch-statement

Trying to use switch in strings by first coverting string into char and then apply switch but still didnt done it....here is my code..

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class HappyBirthday {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String Month;
        char[] Months = Month.toCharArray();
        BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Please enter your month.");

        Month = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter month");
        String month1 = { "January", "feb"};
        char[] month2 = month1.toCharArray();

        // String s=month1.equals(Month);
        // System.out.print(month2Array[0]);
        switch (month2) {

        case 0:
            System.out.println("kool");
            break;

        case 1:
            System.out.println("not kool");
            break;
        default:
        }
    }
}
/**
 * if (month1[1].equals(Month)) System.out.println("kool"); else
 * if(month1[0].equals(Month)) System.out.println("kooooooooooooool"); else
 * System.out.println("Big kooooool");
 **/
```

Comment: I was pretty close to downvoting the question just because the code formatting is a desaster! Please, for the next time, take a minute an clean it up before posting.

Comment: (virtual +1 for skaffman for cleaning up ;-) )

Comment: using string in switch is part of java7

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this [excellent article](http://www.xefer.com/2006/12/switchonstring) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Note that switching on strings will be [supported](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_for_further_consideration) in Java 7.

Comment: According to the changelogs, this code has made it into the codebase.  http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6827009

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can not `switch` on a `String`. The language specification is clear on what you can `switch` on:

#### [JLS 14.11 The `switch` statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.11)

> ```
> SwitchStatement:
>       switch ( Expression ) SwitchBlock
> ```
>
> The type of the `Expression` must be `char`, `byte`, `short`, `int`, `Character`, `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer`, or an `enum` type, or a compile-time error occurs.

Depending on what you want to do, you can `switch` on each `char` of a `String`:

```
    String s = "Coffee, tea, or me?";
    int vowelCount = 0;
    int punctuationCount = 0;
    int otherCount = 0;
    for (char letter : s.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
        switch (letter) {
            case 'A': 
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
                vowelCount++;
                break;
            case ',':
            case '.':
            case '?':
                punctuationCount++;
                break;
            default:
                otherCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("%d vowels, %d punctuations, %d others",
        vowelCount, punctuationCount, otherCount
    ); // prints "7 vowels, 3 punctuations, 9 others"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't switch on a char[] type. Switch on char[0] and use `case 'J':` and so on (although - because some months start with the same letter, the algorithm would be sub-optimal)